# Не могу сделать авторизацию через ключ ssh putty

Tags: linux, авторизация, ssh, putty

Слишком давно не занимался сервером, сейчас память не возвращается, уже есть авторизация по ключу для рута и для другого пользователя, но появилась надобность создать другого и популярное Server refused our key.

1. Создал приватный и публичный ключ в puttygen(rsa), заливаю в директорию своего пользователя pub файл(аналогично смотрел как для предыдущих пользователей было сделано) это получилось /var/www/%user%/data/.sh (isp)
2. Выполняю от рута chown -R %user%:users /var/www/%user%/data/
3. Ставлю на .ssh права 700.
4. Выполняю команду ssh-keygen -i -f /var/www/%user%/data/.sh/key.pub >> /var/www/%user%/data/.sh/authorized_keys
5. Ставлю на authorized_keys права 600.
   Вижу еще сейчас удалил старые логи поставил в sshd конфиге LogLevel DEBUG, перезапустил sshd и логи вообще пустые. Как сделать эту авторизацию?

Comment: Откуда взялась `/var/www/%user%`? Обычно же домашняя директория `/home/%user%`

Comment: Я же пишу (isp) панель управления, она строит иерархию так. home у меня пустая папка вообще

Comment: катало `.ssh` должен быть в домашнем каталоге пользователя, иначе все бестолку. удостоверьтесь, что это действительно так.

Comment: @STC: ISPManager строит так иерархию для сайтов, а вас в данном случае должен интересовать домашний каталог пользователя, а не каталог с сайтом.

Answer (score -1):

> /var/www/%user%/data/.sh/key.pub

Может быть ".ssh"?

> ssh-keygen -i -f

Попробуйте от имени пользователя `%user%`, например, `sudo -u %user%`

Comment: Команды эти исполняются

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score -2):

В конфиге /etc/ssh/sshd_config, настройка AllowUsers не включала нового пользователя, к тому же иногда бывают проблемы с настройкой UsePAM yes, можно переключить на no. ISP Manager строит так иерархию именно для пользователей, а если дело пошло на сайт, то связывает его с пользователем(@МАН69К) Кто имеет дело с панелью, нет смысла идти в home, т.к. домашняя директория для них /var/www/user/data/.

Comment: Домашний каталог - это то, что указано в passwd. И ISPmanager для пользователей создаёт домашний каталог в /home.